# Create default and minified CSS at once

Tags: css, netbeans, sass, compression, minify

I'm using SASS and Netbeans for web development. Is it possible to create the default and minified CSS file at once?

Example: I've one SASS file like style.scss and want as fast as possible two compiled files named style.css and style.min.css

What can I do in Netbeans to get both files at once when I save or precompile my SASS file? Is there any solution or does it need every time a manual step to add compress on the command line, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about Netbeans, but this is a pretty common task you can achieve with Gulp if you're open to using that.